# why I can't use string as id

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a user model with a CrudRepository:

```
    @Entity
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private String username;
        private String password;

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    }

    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

    }
```

However I got an 500 error every time I call findOne():

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository users;

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User register(@RequestBody User userToRegister) {
        String username = userToRegister.getUsername();
        User user = users.findOne(id);
        if (user != null) {
            return null;
        }
        User registeredUser = users.save(userToRegister);
        return registeredUser;
    }
}
```

However if I just switch to an long type id instead of username itself then everything works. I think it's common to use string as id. So how to make this work?

I use the embedded hsql database. I didn't wrote any sql code.

Comment: Surely the error 500 is caused by an exception, which comes with a message and a stack trace, explaining what and where the problem is. Without this information, we're in the dark. So post it. That said, using the user name as ID is a horrible idea. You won't ever be able to change a user name. And you'll have to take care of special characters in the name in every URL containing the ID of the user. And the performance will be inferior.

Comment: Your database uses a number type for auto increment fields.  It's all that makes sense.

Comment: Just removing the @GeneratedValue annotation makes it work. I am using eclipse + junit + retrofit to test the api. I really didn't see any error log in the console. Just some retrofit requests and responses. You made me realize it is really bad to use username as id. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If your intention to generate primary key(String) you need to use UUID, if not you need to remove @GeneratedValue annotation. FYR please check: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-jpa-string-primary-key-example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `String username;` is annotated with both `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`. `@Id` means that is should be a primary key, fine it can be a String. But `@GeneratedValue` means that you want the system to automatically generate a new key when you create a new record. That's easy when the primary key is integer, all databases have a notion of sequence (even if the syntax is not always the same). But if you want String automatically generated keys, you will have do define your own custom generator.

Or if you have no reason for the `@GeneratedValue` annotation, simply remove it as suggested by Bohuslav Burghardt

Comment: I just removed the @GeneratedValue annotation and it worked. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even tho when I removed the @GeneratedValue  and kept just the @Id , it still caused me a problem when creating the database (I'm Using WAMP server by the way).

The solution I found was to fix the column size of my id column in the DataBase

Answer (score 0):

Check are you using
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
and CrudRepository<X, String>

Answer (score -1):

Use column annotation like below by putting nullable False.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
private String username;
```